# Putty + line drawing = weirdness

Tags: linux, putty, rendering

Connecting to any debian installation via PuTTY  results in a very strange situation:
I can have correct display of line drawing, but not for all programs.

In particular Midnight Commander and `aptitude` seem to belong to opposite camps: If one works the other does not.

Currently I have linux set to use utf8 (LANG=en_US.UTF-8) and PuTTY likewise (Window->Translation->{Remote character set: UTF8; Use Unicode line drawing}); in this situation `mc` works as expected and `aptitude` displays "lqqqk".
if I reverse settings in PuTTY (wihout changing anything in linux) (Window->Translation->{Remote character set: ISO-8859-15; Use Unicode line drawing}); this time `aptitude` shows as it should and `mc` displays "ââ€â"; using other "Handling of line drawing characters" breaks `mc` *and* `aptitude`.

Other programs (e.g.: kernel menuconfig) seem to follow `aptitude` behavior.

What's going on "under the hood"?
How do I fix this (if at all possible)?

**UPDATE:** I have been living with this problem (and *NO* solution to be found, I *am* aware of many other answers, but they so address only one half of the problem: mc).
As stated above I *am* able to make mc work correctly and I *thought I was* able to make aptitude/kconfig work correctly... only I need two different settings for them.

**To recap:**

- I have a plain, default debian server (no GUI) install (currently `jessie`, but this holds true for *all* releases)`.
- Locale is pretty standard:

  ```
  $ locale
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  LANGUAGE=en_US:en
  LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_ALL=
  ```

  - I am using either the standard "xterm" setting or "putty" in Connection->Data->{Terminal-type string}; it makes no difference.
  - Certain programs work, others not; if I fix the "not working" ones I contextually break the "working" ones.
  - The "fix" consists in switching PuTTY Window->Translation->{Remote character set} from "UTF8" to "ISO-8859-15" and vice versa.
  - Extreme case is `aptitude` which, I discovered, *can't* be fixed because it seems to use *two* different standards: if menu and scrollbar are displayed right then pop-ups are wrong, and vice-versa.
  - Kernel configuration (`make menuconfig`) shows the same (wrong) behavior as `aptitude`.
  - I include screenshots to explicate better (nothing is changed server-side).

This was taken from KiTTY with `UTF8` setting; note scrollbar is displaying correctly (and also menu (F10) display ok, I did not feel like adding other images, but I can provide, if needed).
[image: This is with UTF8]

This was taken from KiTTY with `ISO-8859-15` setting; note scrollbar is "wrong", but pop-up is correct (in this case also menu are garbled). Notice also the "kind" of mis-translation is different.
[image: This is with ISO-8859-15]

**Please Note:** the question is not (and never was) "How to make mc display line-drawing chars", but "How to have mc and aptitude/kconfig working *in the same environment*".

Comment: Googling for "midnight commander unicode linedrawing" gave me a lot of usefull results. It appears that serverside *and* clientside needs to be aware of the same codepage...

Comment: @agtoever I am aware of those results and tried many of their "solutions", but they address only half of the problem. (sorry for the very late answer, but "real life" caught on me).